# Trying to print DataGrid View with colored cell backgrounds

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

I am using a freeware script to print DataGrid View but the problem I am facing is that although I have colored the cells, when I pass my DataGrid to the PrintDGV freeware code, it doesn't print the colors. I am not familiar with VB.NET or DataGrids so this is my first time trying to attempt this.

**Image of how it currently looks in Print View:**
[image]

**Code:**

http://pastebin.com/0yjvmAp7

Initially I thought that I could just color my DataGrid's cells and pass it to the freeware to print and the freeware would print the background colors too but it seems that isn't true..

Not sure if this is it but here you go:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

' Print Current Schedule Grid Form
' This form displays a list of the print options.
' When you press "OK", control is returned to the Officer Availability window where the specs are read and the actual printing is done.
' You can choose to limit the number of columns, from the Officer area, that are printed
' You can also choose to limit the # rows that are printed to the range selected in schedule.

Public Class PrintOptions

    ' Form Events

    Public Sub New(ByVal availableFields As List(Of String))

        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add all of the displayed Officer specification columns to the columns available to be printed
        For Each field As String In availableFields
            chklst.Items.Add(field, True)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintOptions_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Set the Print Defaults - Print all rows by default and fit calendar to page width by default

        rdoAllRows.Checked = True
        chkFitToPageWidth.Checked = False
    End Sub

    ' Form Butten Events

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    ' Read Form Properties

    Public Function GetSelectedColumns() As List(Of String)
        ' Scroll through the list of available columns and return a list of the columns to be printed
        Dim lst As New List(Of String)
        For Each item As Object In chklst.CheckedItems
            lst.Add(item.ToString)
        Next
        Return lst
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property PrintTitle() As String
        ' Return the title to be used when printing
        Get
            Return txtTitle.Text
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PrintAllRows() As Boolean
        ' Are all rows to be printed or should only the rows selected on the Grid in the Officer Availability window be printed
        Get
            Return rdoAllRows.Checked
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property FitToPageWidth() As Boolean
        ' Compress grid width to fit on page
        Get
            Return chkFitToPageWidth.Checked
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the freeware removes coloring for you (which for a print view seems legit). Skimming through you code I see that PrintPreviewDialog is called. It looks as though that is where the magic happens. Could you paste the code for that as well?

Comment: I have updated the code. After searching the freeware I find that PrintPreviewDialog is in that paste bin code I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by finding out how to change the cell border colors which has worked for me. Here is the snippet:

```
                ' Initialize the random-number generator.
                Randomize()
                ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
                MyAlpha = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
                ' Initialize the random-number generator.
                Randomize()
                ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
                MyRed = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
                ' Initialize the random-number generator.
                Randomize()
                ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
                MyGreen = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))
                ' Initialize the random-number generator.
                Randomize()
                ' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
                MyBlue = CInt(Int((254 * Rnd()) + 0))


                Dim penColor As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(MyAlpha, MyRed, MyGreen, MyBlue))
                ' Drawing Cells Borders 
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penColor, New Rectangle(ColumnLeft(ColPage, ColAt), tmpTop, ColumnWidth(ColPage, ColAt), CellHeight))
```